# creating overlay posts on tumblr

Tags: html, tumblr

I am trying to learn how to create `tumblr` themes, but it has been difficult. I am working on a theme that shows social media buttons when you hover on each photo post by creating overlays. I haven´t been able to figure out the right way to do it for each post. This is the code I have tried for the photo posts:

```
{block:Posts} 
    {block:Photo}
        <div class="post photo smallbox" id="post-{PostID}">
         <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" id="photo"/>
         <div class="wrapper">
             <div class="content">
                 <div class="likebutton">
                 {LikeButton size="100"}  
                 </div>
                 <div class="repostbutton">
                 {ReblogButton size="100"}   
                 </div>
                 <div class="line"></div>
                 <div class="shareBoxBtn">
                     <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={URLEncodedShortURL}" target="_blank">
                         <span class="shareBoxBtn share_twBtn" style="opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"></span>
                         <span class="shareBoxBtnHover share_twBtnHover" style="opacity: 0;"></span>
                     </a>
                     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=221438161314294&link={URLEncodedPermalink}&redirect_uri={URLEncodedPermalink}" target="_blank">
                         <span class="shareBoxBtn share_fbBtn" style="opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"></span>
                         <span class="shareBoxBtnHover share_fbBtnHover" style="opacity: 0;"></span>
                     </a>
                     <a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={URLEncodedPermalink}&media={URLEncodedPhotoURL-500}" target="_blank">
                         <span class="shareBoxBtn share_pinBtn" style="opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"></span>
                         <span class="shareBoxBtnHover share_pinBtnHover" style="opacity: 0;"></span>
                     </a>
                 </div>   
             </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    {/block:Photo}
{/block:Posts}
```

Comment: Describe the behavior you want/expect, and what your code is doing that is different from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
#photo{position:relative}
.wrapper{position:absolute}
```